# Convert the dynamic string to Attributed String

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I want to convert this string to an attributed string. The string is dynamic. In this, the "number" & "'" needs to be a blue color. Example in 5' and 37' should be a blue color.

> "J. Schlupp 5', C. Benteke 37'"

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

let baseString = "J. Schlupp 5', C. Benteke 37'"
let matched = matches(for: "[0-9]'", in: baseString)
print(matched)
```

This returns the following output, from the number 37 it returns 7'

```
["5\'", "7\'"]
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What issues have you faced ? Note that SO is not a code writing service !!!

Comment: Yes i tried, please check the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but I'll give you an idea of how to tackle the problem:

- Create an `NSRegularExpression` that finds instances of `<number>'` in your source string. Run it on your string to find the instances of those substrings.
- Create an `NSMutableAttributedString` from your regular string, and use `addAttributes(_:range:)` to apply your desired attributes (blue colored text) to the ranges found by your `NSRegularExpression`

---

### Edit:

Try using the regular expression "[0-9]+'" to match one or more digits, followed by a `'` character.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use regular expression it does not return the desired output. Instead of 37' I get 7'

Comment: Try replacing `[0-9]` with `\d+` (1 or more digits). `[0-9]+` should also work. (Add a `'` character after the part representing a variable number of digits.

Comment: thank for your help.

Comment: If there are repetative values only there is a problem. Example
"M. Al Harbi 43',Seba 59',C. Guanca 79',F. Martins 90', O. Ighalo 90'"

The second(in this case 90) isn't coloured. as we get the same range.

Comment: Edit your question to provide a better description so we can re-open it.

Comment: Also show the code that does the coloring. When I run your code against the string `"M. Al Harbi 43',Seba 59',C. Guanca 79',F. Martins 90', O. Ighalo 90'"` I get two occurrences of "90'", suggesting that it finds both.

Comment: I see the problem. You take the results of the call to `matches(in:range:)` and map them to the strings found at those locations. Don't do that. Keep your ranges as ranges. Then apply styling to each returned range.